# Umbraco how to publish with all unpublished sub nodes by using umbraco API

Tags: umbraco

I found that the `PublishWithSubs()` method just can publish first level nodes of the parent node.

```
doc.PublishWithSubs(new User(0));
```

How can I publish all the unpublished nodes under one parent node, no matter how deep the unpublished nodes are?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a method on the `Document` class called `PublishWithChildrenWithResult()`. According to the source code, this will recursively publish all content under a branch:

```
   public bool PublishWithChildrenWithResult(User u)
    {
        if (PublishWithResult(u))
        {
            foreach (cms.businesslogic.web.Document dc in Children.ToList())
            {
                dc.PublishWithChildrenWithResult(u);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the newer ContentService API you would do this like so:

```
var cs = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;    
cs.PublishWithChildrenWithStatus(nodeToPublish, includeUnpublished:true)
```

The last parameter allows you to specify if you wish to publish unpublished descendants also.
This method is a bit miss-named, as it will publish all descendants, not just children.